# Did von Neumann answer to Gödel's letter?

Tags: ho.history-overview

On 20 March 1956, Kurt Gödel wrote a famous letter to John von Neumann, in which he formulated the P versus NP question. 
Here is a link to that letter:  [[pdf of letter]](https://www.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~krajicek/goedel-letter.pdf)

I cant seem to find John von Neumann's answer to Gödel's letter online.
Was there one ?

Comment: Famously, there is no known answer to this letter (von Neumann was, I believe, in poor health at the time), but I'm struggling to come up with a reference at the moment.

Comment: @cody, Gödel's own letter mentions von Neumann's poor health.